# Comparing strings in a Textbox

Tags: java

I would like to compare the string in a textbox if it contains "per/kg" and use that to disable a button. I have tried several methods but it did not work please kindly help out.

```
if (productDescTextBox.getText().equals("per/kg"))
    {
        buttonDot.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else buttonDot.setEnabled(false);
```

and this

```
if ("per/kg".equals(productDescTextBox.getText().toString()))
    {
        buttonDot.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else buttonDot.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It's not clear what's not working. Your string detection, or your button enabling/disabling. Have you run this through a debugger ? Have you checked which conditional clause is being executed ? What's the string being passed through via box.getText() ?

Answer (score 1):

use [**String.contains(CharSequence)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
if (productDescTextBox.getText().contains("per/kg"))
```

Comment: Oops. Didn't see you already wrote that. Stupid mobile stack exchange +1 for speed

Answer (score 0):

Use string.contains.

```
if (productDescTextBox.getText().contains("per/kg")){
        //Whatever you want
}
```

Note the method is case sensitive

Comment: Sorry guys, i have tried this method before but the button isn't disabled when the textbox doesn't contain "per/kg"

Comment: But if it contains "per/kg" is it enabled ? If so this method works and there's another error in your code.